# powershell csv subtract one column date value from another one and write result to third where 1 day equals 24 hr

Tags: powershell

could you please help me with powershell script:

In CSV file I need to subtract column B date from column C and write result in column A in format 1 day = 24 hrs and same date = 12 hrs
Sometimes column B can hold future values, in this case column A should contain minus (-)

It should look like this:

```
    120 11/22/2020  11/27/2020
    96  11/23/2020  11/27/2020
    72  11/24/2020  11/27/2020
    48  11/25/2020  11/27/2020
    24  11/26/2020  11/27/2020
    12  11/27/2020  11/27/2020
   -24  11/28/2020  11/27/2020
   -48  11/29/2020  11/27/2020
```

UPD

My script have couple additional steps before subtraction.
I'm taking raw file, TAB delimited, converting it to csv, comparing it with archived files to eliminate duplicates, removing unwanted "SrvDate" column name and replacing it with "TAT\hh" name and then exporting it to file. So the only thing is missing - date comparison and fill hours in "TAT/hh"
Here it is with sample data:

Script:

```
$in = Import-Csv (Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Test\RI\In\test\In\*.csv).Fullname -Delimiter "`t" | ? "Test Code" -in "Z620","Z630"

$in2 = Import-Csv (Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Test\RI\In\test\Arc\*.csv).Fullname

$pcomp = 'Accession'
$dup = Compare-Object $in $in2 -Property $pcomp -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $pcomp
$badhead = $in | Where-Object {$_.$pcomp -notin $dup} | Select-Object *,@{Name='TAT/hh';Expression={$_.'TAT/hh'}} -Exclude 'SrvDate'
$goodhead = $badhead | Select-Object "Accession","TAT/hh","EntryDate","FinalReportDate","Patient First Name","Patient Last Name","DOB","Gender","Race","Ethnicity","Patient Address","Patient City","Patient State","Patient Zip","Patient Phone","Test Code","Test Name","Result","ClientID","Client Name","Phys  ID","Phys  Name"
if ($goodhead) {$goodhead | Where-Object {$_.$pcomp -notin $dup} | Export-Csv "E:\Test\RI\In\test\Out\Client_PtRecords_$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")).csv" -NoTypeInformation}
```

Sample data:

```
Accession   SrvDate EntryDate   FinalReportDate Patient First Name  Patient Last Name   DOB Gender  Race    Ethnicity   Patient Address Patient City    Patient State   Patient Zip Patient Phone   Test Code   Test Name   Result  ClientID    Client Name Phys  ID    Phys  Name
---------   ------- ---------   --------------- ------------------  -----------------   --- ------  ----    ---------   --------------- ------------    -------------   ----------- -------------   ---------   ---------   ------  --------    ----------- --------    ----------
2132900941  NULL    11-24-2020  11-29-2020  MICHELL         PENDERGRAS      9/30/1981   F       U               35 RUSEVELT ST  PRUDENCE    RB  2909    (401)516-5642   Z620    Sars-COVID19    Positive    99984   "ASHRAF FARID, M.D."    50845   ATPAV RIGTED             
2232900942  NULL    11-25-2020  11-29-2020  MICHEL          PENDERGRA       9/30/1982   M       U               315 RUSEVELT ST PRUDENCE    RB  2909    (401)516-5643   Z620    Sars-COVID19    Positive    99984   "ASHRAF FARID, M.D."    50845   ATPAV RIGTED             
2332900943  NULL    11-26-2020  11-29-2020  MICHE           PENDERGR        9/30/1983   F       U               325 RUSEVELT ST PRUDENCE    RB  2909    (401)516-5644   Z620    Sars-COVID19    Positive    99984   "ASHRAF FARID, M.D."    50845   ATPAV RIGTED             
2432900944  NULL    11-27-2020  11-29-2020  MICH        PENDERG     9/30/1984   M       U               335 RUSEVELT ST PRUDENCE    RB  2909    (401)516-5645   Z620    Sars-COVID19    Positive    99984   "ASHRAF FARID, M.D."    50845   ATPAV RIGTED             
2532900945  NULL    11-28-2020  11-29-2020  ALLISO          JEZA            10/13/1977  F       U               15 KAUTEEKEE AVE    SOUTH PRUDENCE  RB  2911    (908)930-9213   Z620    Sars-COVID19    Positive    99984   "ASHRAF FARID, M.D."    50845   ATPAV RIGTED             
2632900946  NULL    11-29-2020  11-29-2020  ALLIS           JEZ             10/13/1978  M       U               151 KAUTEEKEE AVE   SOUTH PRUDENCE  RB  2911    (908)930-9214   Z620    Sars-COVID19    Positive    99984   "ASHRAF FARID, M.D."    50845   ATPAV RIGTED             
2732900947  NULL    11-30-2020  11-29-2020  ALLI            JE              10/13/1979  F       U               152 KAUTEEKEE AVE   SOUTH PRUDENCE  RB  2911    (908)930-9215   Z620    Sars-COVID19    Positive    99984   "ASHRAF FARID, M.D."    50845   ATPAV RIGTED             
2832900948  NULL    12-1-2020   11-29-2020  ALL         J           10/13/1980  M       U               153 KAUTEEKEE AVE   SOUTH PRUDENCE  RB  2911    (908)930-9216   Z620    Sars-COVID19    Positive    99984   "ASHRAF FARID, M.D."    50845   ATPAV RIGTED
```

UPD

I used Алексей's script and insert it in my, but I've faced problem to combine results from two different calculations.

In my script - I'm getting results with correct headers, searched elements only, exporting only if there are results and without duplicates in $goodhead.

In Алексей's script I'm getting calculations for TurnAround Time in $tat (I've selected calculated column only)

Is there a way to fill in $tat into $goodhead?

Here is my updated code:

```
$in = Import-Csv (Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Test\RI\In\test\In\*.csv).Fullname -Delimiter "`t" | ? "Test Code" -in "Z620","Z630"

$in2 = Import-Csv (Get-ChildItem -Path E:\Test\RI\In\test\Arc\*.csv).Fullname

$pcomp = 'Accession'
$dup = Compare-Object $in $in2 -Property $pcomp -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $pcomp
$badhead = $in | Where-Object {$_.$pcomp -notin $dup} | Select-Object *,@{Name='TAT/hh';Expression={$_.'TAT/hh'}} -Exclude 'SrvDate'
$goodhead = $badhead | Select-Object "Accession","TAT/hh","EntryDate","FinalReportDate","Patient First Name","Patient Last Name","DOB","Gender","Race","Ethnicity","Patient Address","Patient City","Patient State","Patient Zip","Patient Phone","Test Code","Test Name","Result","ClientID","Client Name","Phys ID","Phys Name"

$tatin = $goodhead | Select-Object * | % {
    $EntryDate = [datetime]::parseexact($_.EntryDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd', $null)
    $FinalReportDate = [datetime]::parseexact($_.FinalReportDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd', $null)

    $tatcalc = switch (($FinalReportDate - $EntryDate).TotalDays){
        0 {12}
        default {$_ * 24}
    }
    [PSCustomObject]@{
        'TAT/hh' = $tatcalc
        EntryDate = $EntryDate
        FinalReportDate = $FinalReportDate
    }

}

$tat = $tatin | Select "TAT/hh"

if ($tat) {$tat | Sort-Object "Result" -Descending | Export-Csv "E:\Test\RI\In\test\Out\Client_PtRecords_$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")).csv" -NoTypeInformation}
```

Thank you!

P.S. I'm just a beginner with Powershell, trying to learn it on daily tasks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, Aleksandr. It might help to edit your question with an example of your source data and any snippets of code that you've tried so far.

Comment: Ryan, thank you for your suggestion, I did update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$in = Import-Csv (Get-ChildItem -Path D:\tmp\alex\Client_PtRecords_20201203.csv).Fullname -Delimiter "`t" | ? "Test Code" -in "Z620","Z630"

$in2 = Import-Csv (Get-ChildItem -Path D:\tmp\alex\arc\Client_PtRecords_20201202.csv).Fullname

$pcomp = 'Accession'
$dup = Compare-Object $in $in2 -Property $pcomp -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent -PassThru | Select-Object -ExpandProperty $pcomp
$badhead = $in | Where-Object {$_.$pcomp -notin $dup} | Select-Object *,@{Name='TAT/hh';Expression={$_.'TAT/hh'}} -Exclude 'SrvDate'
$goodhead = $badhead | Select-Object "Accession", @{name = "TAT/hh"; expression = {switch(([datetime]::parseexact($_.FinalReportDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd', $null)-[datetime]::parseexact($_.EntryDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd', $null)).TotalDays){ 0 {12}; default {$_ * 24}}}},"EntryDate","FinalReportDate","Patient First Name","Patient Last Name","DOB","Gender","Race","Ethnicity","Patient Address","Patient City","Patient State","Patient Zip","Patient Phone","Test Code","Test Name","Result","ClientID","Client Name","Phys ID","Phys Name"

$tatin = $goodhead | Select-Object * 

$tat = $tatin | Select "TAT/hh"

if ($tat) {$tat | Sort-Object "Result" -Descending | Export-Csv "D:\tmp\alex\arc\Client_PtRecords_$((Get-Date).ToString("yyyyMMdd")).csv" -NoTypeInformation}
```

Comment: Алексей, thank you for your answer, I tried to insert your script in mine, but unfortunately, the most I've received a line like this "-17706144 11/26/2020 00:00:00 11/28/2020 00:00:00", so I need to find a way to insert it into my script.

Comment: is't well formed CSV in "Sample data"

Comment: Алексей, could you please explain me how to correctly insert your code to my script so I will receive all data in headers listed in $goodhead (as I'm getting now) plus data which will be received from your code and will be filled in "TAT\hh" column. Thank you!